# Eclipse doesn't run android app when I click Run

Tags: android

I'm trying to do the [first app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) tutorial. After editing the 2 xml files, activity_main and strings, the instructions say, "In Eclipse, click Run from the toolbar."

First off, it showed me some problems. With the EditText set to `android:layout_weight="1"`, it doesn't like the `android:layout_height` set to `wrap_content` and shows me on the Problems tab. The problem goes away if I set layout_height to 0dp like the width.

Second, now that it shows me nothing in the problems list, hitting run doesn't do anything, either on the windows computer or on my android device connected via usb and set up according to the previous instructions.

I found another thread with similar question. They suggested he look at his AndroidManifest.xml and MainActivity.java. Mine seem to contain what they suggested needed to be there. Oh! I see my avid is open, but it doesn't seem to say anything.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <EditText android:id = "@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text = "@string/button_send"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Edit your message, silly.</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_man">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Is your device detected? Does it build your project?

Comment: make sure your project is selected: click on your project->click run

Comment: You might need to reset adb in your DDMS tab or the good 'ol => disconnect the device, shut Eclipse down, reconnect the device(first), let your machine recognize it, then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 8):

The Run button in Eclipse doesn't function when you're on an XML file.  Open up one of the .java files, then hit Run - it should compile and run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AVD for using emulator or make sure your phone is detected by eclipse. Also go to Run Configurations,create a new configuration for Android Application and select your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce this error:

> First off, it showed me some problems. With the EditText set to
>   android:layout_weight="1", it doesn't like the android:layout_height
>   set to "wrap_content" and shows me on the Problems tab.

Even if your app runs, it will only show the button on the right side of the display. The `EditText` will not be visible. This is because you are setting the `EditText's` height to `0dp`.

Since you are setting the `layout_weight` attribute of the `EditText` to `1`, and the `LinearLayout's` orientation is `horizontal`(by default), you only need to set the width of `EditText` to `0dp`. This will make the `EditText` take as much width as it can with the rest taken by the button, whose width is set to wrap_content.

This should help you understand the options you have while working with `LinearLayouts`: [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: So how is a NOOB supposed to understand this when the example given is **WRONG**? Stackoverflow won't let me show a picture of what I'm getting, but my "5554 Nonsense AVD" shows a black box with some controls on the right, but no text box or button. Eclipse's log at the bottom says Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... then gives up saying emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'barefootelectronics.com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity activity launch'! the black box stays black.

Comment: @TomtheNewb I went through the same when I first picked up Android programming 3 months ago. Endless stream of errors. Took me quite a while to get my first activity up and running. It will take time. Follow as many tutorials as you can. Familiarity with Java goes a long way too. I hope you get through this initial phase. It'll make sense soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using Eclipse. Did you actually start your virtual device? When I created my first project, I created the virtual device but forgot to actually click start. Nothing happened when I clicked run.

Try right clicking on your project and going to Run As -> Android App.

Comment: Hmm. Under run-as, I see (none applicable). My AVD, "5554 Nonsense AVD" appears, the log at the bottom of eclipse says

Answer (score 0):

Boy its not a problem. You just have to select your application and run it as an android app. Moreover, check in AVD manager that either you have your virtual machine up and running. If not then start it first. Assuming that you have already created your AVD. Now goto the main activity and hit the run button and yupiee. =P